# transfer multi data from multiple activities to one activity AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 3 activity , activity1 have edit Text and activity2 have another edit text and last activity is result , so when I add text to activity1 and press next to go activity2 I will add another text then press next to go to last activity and here we will see result of activity1 and 2
thanks

Comment: Hi There. Try adding more code sample and explain what you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be your first activity:

```
void goToActivity2() {
    var intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("THE_KEY_FOR_TEXT", "text_from_editText");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the activity2 you can get the text:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        var textFromTheFirstActivity = getIntent.getStringExtra("THE_KEY_FOR_TEXT")
    }
```

Then you do the same to pass the text for other activitys.